# Optimize Mongodb documents versioning

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In my application I have need to load a lot of data and compare it to existing documents inside a specific collection, and version them.

In order to do it, for every new document I have to insert, I simply made a query and search for last version, using a specific key (not _id), group data together and found last version.

Example of data:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c73a643f9bc1c2fg4ca6ef5"),
    "data" : {
            the data
        }
    },
    "key" : {
        "value1" : "545454344",
        "value2" : "123212321",
        "value3" : "123123211"
    },
    "version" : NumberLong("1"),
}
```

As you can see, key is composed of three values, related to data and my query to find last version is the following:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    {
            {
                "$sort" : {
                    "version" : NumberInt("-1")
                }
            },
            {
                "$group" : {
                    "_id" : "$key",
                    "content" : {
                        "$push" : "$data"
                    },
                    "version" : {
                        "$push" : "version"
                    },
                    "_oid" : {
                        "$push" : "$_id"
                    },
                }
            },
            {
                "$project" : {
                    "data" : {
                        "$arrayElemAt" : [
                            "$content",
                            NumberInt("0")
                        ]
                    },
                    "version" : {
                        "$arrayElemAt" : [
                            "$version",
                            NumberInt("0")
                        ]
                    },
                    "_id" : {
                        "$arrayElemAt" : [
                            "$_oid",
                            NumberInt("0")
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
    }
)
```

To improve performance (from exponential to linear), I build an index that holds key and version:

```
db.getCollection("collection").createIndex({ "key": 1, "version" : 1})
```

So my question is: there are some other capabilities/strategies to optimize this search ?

**Notes**

- in these collection there are some other field I already use to filter data using match, omitted for brevity
- my prerequisite is to load a lot of data, process one to one, before insert: if there is a better approach to calculate version, I can consider also to change this
- I'm not sure if an [unique index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/) on key could do the same as my query. I mean, if I do an unique index on key and version, I could have the uniqueness on that couple an iterate on it, for example:

  - no data on collection: just insert first version
  - insert new document: try to insert version 1, then get error, iterate on it, this should hit unique index, right ?

Comment: Not sure about the optimization part. What is the issue ? You can rewrite your query as `db.collection.aggregate(
    {
            {
                "$sort" : {
                    "version" : NumberInt("-1")
                }
            },
            {
                "$group" : {
                    "_id" : "$key",
                    "data" : {
                        "$first" : "$$ROOT"
                    }})`

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I appreciated it. The point is to get, for every new document that i need to insert (I mean, a lot of them) I must do a query to calculate new version

Comment: You are welcome. Don’t insert one at a time bulk insert them. So first step would be to get last version data for all documents followed by iterating new documents and adding the last version data by looking up in the aggregated results and bulk insert. That way you will do one query to get all data and few bulk insert queries to insert the data. If you need more help please add some more code showing all the steps that you do now.

Comment: I'm not sure about this part "So first step would be to get last version data for all documents " this means load in memory all documents, right ?

Comment: okay if they are too many to load into memory. Use cursor to process them in batch,

Comment: Yes, Is what I'm doing right now. Do you have feedback on using an unique index too ?

Comment: You could just use a timestamp as version, in most cases it should be unique enough and it doesn't need to be computed so your inserts would be much faster.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion! I've explained on problem description that in my case id cannot be used, but instead a field key. Maybe I'm not understanding your answer properly ?

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. As far as I can tell, the only reason you need all the data is because you have to know the last version number so you can set the new version number when you are inserting the document. This is in my opinion unnecessary, you can just use a Unix timestamp as version (`System.currentTimeMillis()` on java). This would eliminate the need for this complicated lookup query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar situation and this is how I solved it.

- Create a seperate collection that will hold Key and corresponding latest version, say KeyVersionCollection

  - Make this collection "InMemory" for faster response
  - Store Key in "_id" field
- When inserting document in your versioned collection, say EntityVersionedCollection

  - Query latest version from KeyVersionCollection
  - Update the version number by 1 or insert a new document with version 0 in KeyVersionCollection
  - You can even combine above 2 operations in 1 (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#db.collection.findAndModify)
  - Use new version number to insert document in EntityVersionedCollection

This will save time of aggregation and sorting. On side note, I would keep latest versions in seperate collection - EntityCollection. In this case, for each entity - insert a new version in EntityVersionedCollection and upsert it in EntityCollection.

In corner cases, where process is interrupted between getting new version number and using it while inserting entity, you might see that the version is skipped in EntityVersionedCollection; but that should be ok. Use timestamps to track inserts/updates so that it can be used to correlate/audit in future.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, I thinkg your approach will be one I will follow to solve my scenario

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass an array into the mongoDB insert function, and it should insert an entire JSON payload without any memory deficiencies.

You're welcome